# Cómo seleccionar los máximos registros agrupados por otro criterio

Tags: mysql

Me gustaría poder seleccionar la máxima cantidad, agrupados por subasta_id. En la tabla que figura, el resultado deseado es:

- que de la subasta_id 3 se obtenga el registro     231.53        4          3
- que de la subasta_id 4 se obtenga el registro     266.26        3          4

  ```
   cantidad, pujador_id, subasta_id
    200.00        2          3
    230.00        2          4
    210.00        2          3
    241.50        2          4
    220.50        3          3
    253.58        3          4
    266.26        3          4
    231.53        4          3
  ```

He probado: select MAX(p.cantidad), p.pujador_id, p.subasta_id from pujas p group by p.subasta_id;

```
 MAX(p.cantidad)    pujador_id  subasta_id
      231.53             2          3
      266.26             2          4
```

Pero esta consulta no devuelve el pujador_id correcto

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente di con la respuesta a través de una subconsulta que devuelve un conjunto de resultados y usando una cláusula in sobre ese conjunto

```
select p.cantidad, p.pujador_id, p.subasta_id from pujas p
where p.cantidad in 
(select max(p2.cantidad)from pujas p2 group by p2.subasta_id);
```

La subconsulta--> select max(p2.cantidad)from pujas p2 group by p2.subasta_id)
devuelve los máximos de cada agrupación de subasta:

```
max(p2.cantidad)
    231.53
    266.26
```

Y la consulta externa los registros que cumplen (in) con la condición de la subconsulta.

```
cantidad    pujador_id  subasta_id
  266.26         3          4 
  231.53         4          3
```